# Merge 3 ISO file segments into 1 complete ISO file

Tags: dvd, iso-image, binary-files, dell-poweredge

I need to merge 3 ISO files from Dell website and they state the following:

> Download all ISO file segments into an
>   empty subdirectory on your local hard
>   drive. After you have downloaded all
>   the file segments, run the following
>   command to create the ISO file:
>
> `copy /b om* om650_suu_dvrpck_a00.iso [Windows]`

I have created an empty directory on `C:` called `b` and dumped the ISO's into that directory, opened up CMD and tried the above; however, I get the following message:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
0 file(s) copied.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are in the correct directory in the command prompt when you are running the copy command. "/b" is not referring to a directory to place the files in, but a command-line switch to tell copy that it's appending a binary file.

Comment: i.e. when you open the command prompt the first command you run should be `cd c:\b` to place yourself into the folder named "b" indicated in your question. then run the command from Dell

Comment: the above is correct. The command is saying "copy, using binary mode, all files whose name begins with the letters 'om' to the destination file 'om650_suu_dvrpck_a00.iso'". It may not be clear, but the "[Windows]" part should NOT be typed, it is not part of the command.

Comment: Ah that explains that and thank you very much for your help.